# Get the list of layers in a store from geoserver

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

Is there a way to get the all the layers present in a store in geoserver?

My JS file contains code for each layer present in a store. So when I publish a new layer in geoserver I have to manually include the code of the new layer in JS. But what I want is to put a for loop in JS with the layer names present in a store, like

```
for(i<=all layers present in store)                 
{
   var wmslayer2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Layer2","http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", 
   {'layers': '**cite:layer[i]**', 'format':'image/png', 'transparent':'true'},
   {'opacity': 1.0, 'isBaseLayer': false, 'visibility': true}); 
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The restconfig api allows you to do this:

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/restconfig/rest-config-api.html

You can request data be sent back in JSON as well which is handy from javascript code. The WMS caps has the same info but it is a huge xml document... so expensive to parse on the client side.

Comment: +1 http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/restconfig/rest-config-api.html#data-stores

Comment: can you plz tell me how to request the data in any format?? i mean is it through a url or any command to be given or by a php/html file or etc??? I mean I dont know how to execute those operations specified in ur link

Comment: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/index.html

Comment: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/datastores.html 
https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/api/#1.0.0/datastores.yaml

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the [GetCapabilities](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getcapabilities) request contains a list of all layers offered by the server. But it's probably easier to create a layer group in Geoserver that simply contains all layers. Then you only have to request that group.

Comment: But layer group contains all the layers which are shown as a single layer on map. I mean my layer switcher has only a single overlay at that time, Is it not???