# Doing OpenLayers.Request in OpenLayers 3

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, rest

I have been searching for solutions to call GeoServer REST api from OpenLayers 3 for a long time.

I found that for OpenLayers 2, [there is](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30085/how-to-get-names-of-all-layers-in-a-store-in-geoserver-using-openlayers) a OpenLayers class `OpenLayers.Request` for doing this:
http://docs.openlayers.org/library/request.html

But for OpenLayers 3, I can't find a similar class. 
I tried a lot of online code for PHP proxying (andjsonp) trying to do the same without `OpenLayers.Request`, to no avail.

What is the correct/most reliable way to call GeoServer Rest from OpenLayers3 (or even general JavaScript with jQuery/AJAX)?

Answer (score 2):

Internally OL3 uses Google Closure XhrIo to load data in vector layers.

OL3 philosophy has changed, now is a more *concrete* library, mainly oriented for gis mapping, instead a *general* purpose library like OL2.

OL3 leave to the user tasks like AJAX request. You can make them using XMLHttpRequest or through any other library like jQuery or Google Closure.